# Checkboxes hide groups of rows from a table

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a table that I would like to dynamically hide/reveal rows in, based on checkboxes at the top.

I would like to do this without jQuery, just vanilla Javascript.

I have seen numerous methods on this site and others, but always snippets of code,not complete working examples.

I don't want to give each row a separate div name, or whatever, I am assuming there is a way I can do this with a common class for the 3 types of rows I want to hide/reveal.

Can anyone please show me a working example which allows checkboxes to hide/show multiple rows from a table with vanilla Javascript?

Comment: What HTML are you working with? How does/should a particular checkbox relate to a particular row?

Comment: As in my example to the answer below, there are ... say.. 200 teams some of which are "North" Teams, some of which are "South"and some of which are "Out of County" teams. The list is sorted descending by total raised, regardless of which group the team is in. I want 3 checkboxes to be able to add/remove the row of those groups of teams depending on what the end-user wants to see.So they can compare just their regions' teams against each other. That sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given HTML like the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="show" value="north" checked />North</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="show" value="south" checked />South
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="show" value="outOfArea" checked />Out of area
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="north">
            <td>North One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="north">
            <td>North Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="outOfArea">
            <td>Out-of-area One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="south">
            <td>South One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="south">
            <td>South Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="north">
            <td>North Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="north">
            <td>North Four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="south">
            <td>South Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="outOfArea">
            <td>Out-of-area Two</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The following jQuery seems to do as you *seem* to describe:

```
$('thead input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var self = this;
    $(self).closest('table').find('tbody tr').filter('.' + self.value).toggle(self.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J3b6Y/).

As it seems that you'd prefer a plain-JavaScript approach, I'd suggest the following (to work on the same HTML as posted above):

```
function toggle (e) {
    var self = e.target,
        toggleClass = '.' + self.value,
        toToggle = document.querySelectorAll(toggleClass);
    for (var i = 0, len = toToggle.length; i < len; i++) {
        toToggle[i].style.display = self.checked ? 'table-row' : 'none';
    }
}

var thead = document.querySelector('thead');
thead.addEventListener('change', toggle);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J3b6Y/1/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: Looks great on jsfiddle,thank you! I seem to be missing something though with the js.  I put it in <script type="text/javascript"></script>.. but what makes it start? I've done some onload= but not much. I don't really know javascript, but I've gotten some stuff to work nicely from web examples before.

Comment: Checking/un-checking the `input` check-boxes should 'make it start.' Though this assumes that you're using an up-to-date browser? It should certainly work in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. I'm not sure when, or if, IE began to implement `addEventListener()`. Of course you do need to the DOM to be present/constructed before binding events to DOM nodes, so personally I'd wrap it in a `script` tag (as you are) and place that `script` tag just before the `</body>` (closing) tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are describing something along the lines of [this example](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/javascript/hiding-and-unhiding-table-rows/)

Comment: If you're linking to an external resource at the *very least* it would be appreciated if you could summarise the resource you're linking to in your answer. Stack Overflow is meant to be able to stand alone, and have useful answers/code in the answers/questions. Links are great for linking to additional resources, references and demonstrations of the code in-action, but the answer should be able to exist without them (to guard against link-rot and site-reorganisation).

Comment: I see what you are saying, though, his question was for a working example. I realize I could have taken the example apart and explained it and perhaps I should have.

Comment: This works great for individual rows, but what I am looking for is for it to control groups of rows, which will not be sorted by group. For instance, a list of teams in a fundraiser, where I want to enable/disable display of "North side" teams, "South Side" Teams, and "Out of County" teams.  it's a totals page sorted descending by total, so South Side may want to see how they're doing against each other rather than against other teams intermixed in there.