# Show/Hide row in a table using checkboxes

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, show-hide, tablerow

This is a page I am working on to show all the hacking Programs for Infinity (the miniature wargame).

http://wargames.malgol.se/infinity/hacking/

The function I'm looking for is by clicking the various checkbox under HACKING DEVICE: and UPGRADE: I want the table rows connected to them be displayed and the connecting icons for it. If I for example check "Hacking Device Plus", all the rows and programs connected to it will show up and they will all have the light green "square" show up in the Device column and if select more checkbox and more then one Hacking Device have the same row both "squares" will be shown.

If none of the checkbox are selected all the rows will be shown.

What I also want is every odd and even row to have a different colour. Now I am using this to change colour but it I can't get it to work with the solution I found here to change the active row colour (see below).

```
table#hackingTable tr:nth-child(odd) td {background:#303030;color:#F7F7F7;}
table#hackingTable tr:nth-child(even) td {background:#404040;color:#F7F7F7;}
```

For the active row to change colour I tried the solution I found here. 
[Tip://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970983/change-background-color-of-a-table-row-on-click](http://Tip://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970983/change-background-color-of-a-table-row-on-click)

I have though about using the same solution to hide rows that aren't checked but after testing to just hide the css I used for odd/even colour didn't work since it could turn up the same colour next to each other when I hide the row in the middle.

Right now I am using class to show what row is connected to what hacking Device and Update.

```
<tr class="hdRow hdpRow">
```

And this is the code I use for all the squares.

```
    <td>
        <div class="cube hdCube"></div>
        <div class="cube hdpCube"></div>
    </td>
```

I hope I'm more clear of what I want now then I was the last time I asked something here. =)

Comment: So I have found this question that almost working. The problem is that if I have unchecked a program that is used by a Hacking Device that still checked that row will still disappear. Is there a way too check if that row has more then one class and if any of them is still checked, keep it visable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190233/checkboxes-hide-groups-of-rows-from-a-table

Comment: My testpage
http://malgol.se/labs/wargames/infinity/hacking/

Comment: My solution still works, you just can't put the `checkbox`'s inside the labels, inside the table, ... they need to be _before_ the `table` in the markup, or else you can't use their `checked` state. I will update my answer one more time, showing that explicit

Comment: Updated my answer showing how you need to structure your markup

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It does work now. The only thing I'm having problem with is hiding the different coloured squares in the Device column. If I for example only have Assault checked I only want the lilac square to be shown. http://malgol.se/labs/wargames/infinity/hacking/ (sorry for a late reply, been busy with other real work)

Comment: The lilac squares and/or the rows they represent?

Comment: Only the squares. I want only the squares that's connected to the selected Hacking Devices (Plus, Assault,Defencive etc) to be shown. So if i only check Hacking Device, only the darker green Square should be shown in the Device column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start

*Note that the input needs to be before both the label and the table in the markup to be able to use its `checked` state*

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody tr {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
tr, td {
  padding: 10px;
}
input,
tbody tr {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
}
label:after {
  content: '\00a0';
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#inp1:checked ~ table label[for="inp1"]:after,
#inp2:checked ~ table label[for="inp2"]:after,
#inp3:checked ~ table label[for="inp3"]:after {
  content: 'v';
}
#inp1:checked ~ table .nr1,
#inp2:checked ~ table .nr2,
#inp3:checked ~ table .nr3 {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp1" type="checkbox">
<input id="inp2" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="inp3" type="checkbox">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr colspan="3">
      <td>
        <label for="inp1">Toggle 1</label>
        <label for="inp2">Toggle 2</label>
        <label for="inp3">Toggle 3</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="nr1">
      <td><div>Row 1</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nr2">
      <td><div>Row 2</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nr3">
      <td><div>Row 3</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
      <td><div>...</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wait what? This is all CSS? Didn't even know this was possible. I'll try it out. Thank you! =)

Comment: I am using php and require_once to request a php-file where I have the table and another where I have the checkbox menu. The first problem I found is that the checkboxes won't work if I place them in the requested php-files, only if I have them in that same as the table. The second is the squares have the same padding as the div's that contains the text inside the table.

Comment: @MAlgol Show me the rendered html .. it is all about how the table and the input relates in the markup structure

Comment: @MAlgol Are we talking about all the different "Hacking device" check boxes?

Comment: @MAlgol If we are, you need to move them outside the `li`, and put them where my test `inp1` is, and use a label as the visual check mark in their place ... will update my answer soon showing how it can be done

Comment: @MAlgol Updated with a simple sample

Comment: That didn't really fix the problem with the squares inside the Device column. And I'm not sure what to do to make different checkboxes show/hide different rows.

Comment: @MAlgol I can't do much more than show you the technique how to do it, you'll need to find a way how to implement it

Comment: And I thank you for that. It was an interesting solution, just not mine.